# I am kind of newbie guys and i made a line of code in my tic tac toe game to print 100 new lines so the history of the board won't show

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am kind of newbie guys and i made a line of code in my tic tac toe game  to print 100 new lines so the history of the board won't show and now the problem is that the string where it says who's turn it is wont show because it is left 100 lines above.I tried to make some changes but with no succes.

````
def display_board(board):
    print("\n"*100)
    print("""
▀█▀ █ █▀▀   ▀█▀ ▄▀█ █▀▀   ▀█▀ █▀█ █▀▀
░█░ █ █▄▄   ░█░ █▀█ █▄▄   ░█░ █▄█ ██▄

        █▀▀ ▄▀█ █▀▄▀█ █▀▀
        █▄█ █▀█ █░▀░█ ██▄""")
    print("\n"*1)
    print(board[7]+"|"+board[8]+"|"+board[9])
    print("-----")
    print(board[4]+"|"+board[5]+"|"+board[6])
    print("-----")
    print(board[1]+"|"+board[2]+"|"+board[3])

def place_marker(board):

    marker = " "

    while marker != "x" and marker != "o":
        marker = input("Player 1, choose x or o: ")

    player1 = marker    

    if player1 == "x":
        player2 = "o"       
        print("""   
                |------------------------------------|
                | Player 1 is now X and player 2 is O|   
                |------------------------------------|  
                                                     """)       
    else:
        player2 = "x"  
        print("""   
                |------------------------------------|
                | Player 1 is now O and player 2 is X| 
                |------------------------------------|
                                                      """)      

#Input of the player
    count = 0   
    for a in range(9):
        count += 1

        display_board(board)

        position = int(input("Choose a number between 1-9: "))

        board[position] = marker


        if board[1] == board[2] == board[3] != ' ':

            win_check = str(board[1] + " HAS WON !!!")
            print(win_check)
            break

        elif board[1] == board[5] == board[9] != ' ':

            variabila1 = str(board[1] + " HAS WON !!!")
            print(variabila1)
            break

        elif board[7] == board[8] == board[9] != ' ':

            variabila2 = str(board[7] + " HAS WON !!!")
            print(variabila2)
            break

        elif board[7] == board[5] == board[3] != ' ':

            variabila3 = str(board[7] + " HAS WON !!!")
            print(variabila3)
            break
        elif board[1] == board[4] == board[7] != ' ':

            variabila4 = str(board[1] + " HAS WON !!!")
            print(variabila4)
            break

        elif board[3] == board[6] == board[9] != ' ':

            variabila5 = str(board[3] + " HAS WON !!!")
            print(variabila5)
            break
        elif count == 9:
            print("THIS IS A TIE")
        #if statement pentru a schimba markeru dupa fiecare mutare
        if marker =="x":
            marker = "o" 
            print("Now it's (O)'s turn : ") 

        else:
             marker = "x"
             print("Now it's (X)'s turn : ")   



    return(a)
    return (player1,player2)
place_marker(board)


#restart function
def clear_board(board):


    restart = input("Would you like to play again?:\nyes/no: ")
    while restart == "yes":
        board = [" "]*10
        place_marker(board)
        clear_board(board)
    else:
        restart == "no"
        print("Hope you enjoyed it!!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    clear_board(board)```
````

Comment: What is your main problem? Please mentioned explicitly.

Comment: When the board is displayed i made the game to print who's turn it is above the table at line 92 and 96 ,if it is x's turn the program should say "Now it's (X)'s turn :" and it worked just fine but because i didn't wanted a history of the board,at the start i wrote this: ```print("\n"*100) ``` and because of that,now the program prints the "Now it's (X)'s turn :" 100 lines above the board and the player can't see it

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `display_board` in the `place_marker` function. And `display_board` function prints out 100 newlines. I'd suggest you should print 100 newlines whenever the game is finished and you need restart. In here perhaps:

```py
#restart function
def clear_board(board):

    print("\n"*100)
    restart = input("Would you like to play again?:\nyes/no: ")
    while restart == "yes":
        board = [" "]*10
        place_marker(board)
        clear_board(board)
    else:
        restart == "no"
        print("Hope you enjoyed it!!!")
```

I am confused about why are you using while loop in clear_board function too, you probably meant `if restart=="yes"`